# bitbucket - solve conflicts and preserve atomic feature branches

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge-conflict

Given the following git workflow:

- a feature branch **fb1** is created from master branch (production stable codebase)
- when dev done a pull-request is created, then *fb1* is merged to **release-branch-1.x.x**
- another feature branch **fb2** is created from master
- when dev is done on *fb2* another pull-request is created and attempted to be merged to **release-branch-1.x.x** but fails due to a conflict (most likely introduced by some code in *fb1*)

According to [the documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-merge-conflicts-704414003.html) solving this conflict implies that **release-branch-1.x.x** (which contains *fb1* code) be merged in **fb2** locally, decide what to keep (solve conflict), then **fb2** be pushed to remote to update the pull-request.

This solves the conflict all right, but adds all the work on **release-branch-1.x.x** to **fb2** which is something I would like to avoid. Say I want to revert the **fb1** merge commit, the *fb1* code will still be on the release branch because it was introduced by **fb2**.

Any thoughts on how can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most workflows, the owner of each feature branch is responsible for keeping their branch up to date with whatever the "official" line of code is (To be as generic as possible, I'll call the integration branch master, though it can be develop, release, or other name in various workflows). So the full sequence for your scenario would look like this:

1. Developer 1 starts **fb1** from **master**
2. Developer 2 starts **fb2** from **master**
3. Developer 1 completes his feature and submits **pr1** to merge **fb1** into **master**
4. **fb1** is tested and approved and **pr1** is accepted, **master** is updated to contain *initial + fb1*
5. Developer 2 completes her feature but finds her branch is now out of date
6. Developer 2 merges **master** into **fb2** and resolves the conflicts her branch now contains *initial + fb1 + fb2*
7. Developer 2 submits a **pr2** to merge **fb2** into **master**
8. A serious bug is found resulting from feature1, so the merge of **fb1** to **master** is reverted and master now contains *initial* only
9. **fb2** is now out of date because **master** has been altered and if there were conflicts resolved before, they will occur again with the original code restored so that **pr2** will not be able to automatically merge and bitbucket will warn you.
10. Developer 2 merges **master** into **fb2** and resolve the conflicts, making her branch contain *initial + fb2*
11. Developer 2 pushes to update **pr2** which is then approved and merged, resulting in a **master** branch that contains *initial + fb2*

Git uses the most recent common ancestor of two commits when merging, not the original point where the code diverged. Even if there were no conflicts, when the changes from **master** including **fb1**, are integrated into **fb2**, the common ancestor between those two branches would be a point on master containing *initial + fb1*, if **fb1** was subsequently removed from master, git would see those changes had occurred on the master branch and the resulting merge would not contain those changes.

You can think of a merge algebraically, where `m = merge`, `b = base`, `l = left`, `r = right`, `f = feature` and `i = initial`

```
m = b        + diff(b,l)           + diff(b,r)
m = (i + f1) + diff((i + f1), (i)) + diff((i + f1), (i + f1 + f2))
m = (i + f1) + (-f1)               + (f2)
m = i  + (f1 + -f1)                + (f2)
m = i + f2
```

Comment: what would have happened if the pr2 would have been merged before the bug was found (step 7). btw, that's a really nice explanation @LightBender

Comment: adding to the comment above: pr1 would be reverted but pr1 code would still remain on master because it was also introduced when pr2 was merged (which at the time of merge contained pr1 code from the sync with master)

Comment: @Radu Reverting a commit does not remove the commit from the history, instead a new commit that reverses the changes is added. So reverting the changes on pr1 would remove those changes from master entirely regardless of how many intermediate commits contained that code.